# How can i get the new X and Y position after rotating?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to make a Sunflowerplot and after rotating the lines the position of them has to be translated back. But i don't know how to get the new x,y pos after rotating.

I want to rotate only the line but its position does ofcourse change too.

```
var xOld = (save[i][0])/(xS.value/100/3.4);
var yOld = (save[i][1])/(yS.value/100/3.5*-1); 

//Above code is to get and transform the position where to draw
//and works very well without rotate

var line = d3.select("svg")
        .append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width","1")
    //Backwardline
        .attr("x1",xOld-lineLength)
    .attr("y1",yOld)
        //I think that i need to translate the new position here
    .attr("transform", "translate(50, " + 360  +") rotate(" + 45 * -1+ ")")
    //Forwardline
    .attr("x2",(xOld)+lineLength)
    .attr("y2",(yOld))
    .style("stroke","blue");
```

Comment: Have you considered using `path` instead of a `line`? You can easily draw curved and rotated lines as a single element with that. Can you also provide some more context about what the sunflower pot should look like?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot No, i didn't but that sounds great! Yes it should look similar to this https://static.packt-cdn.com/products/9781783989508/graphics/9508OS_07_01.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a snippet where you can determine the number of petals yourself, and play with the styling and rotation a little if you want

```js
const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

// The distance in pixels between the edge and the center of each petal
const petalRadius = 20;

// sin, cos, and tan work in radians
const fullCircle = 2 * Math.PI;

// Zero rads make the shape point to the right with the right angle
// Use - 0.5 * pi rads to make the first petal point upwards instead
// You can play with this offset to see what it does
const offset = - Math.PI / 2;

function drawSunflower(container, petals) {
  const radsPerPetal = fullCircle / petals;
  const path = container.append('path');

  // We're going to need this a lot. M moves to the given coordinates, in this case
  // That is the center of the sunflower
  const goToCenter = ` M ${petalRadius},${petalRadius}`;

  // Construct the `d` attribute. Start in the center and work form there.
  let d = goToCenter;
  let counter = 0;
  while (counter < petals) {
    const rads = counter * radsPerPetal + offset;
    const dx = Math.cos(rads) * petalRadius;
    const dy = Math.sin(rads) * petalRadius;

    // Draw a relative line to dx, dy, then go to center
    d += `l ${dx},${dy}` + goToCenter;
    counter += 1;
  }
  path.attr('d', d);
}

const transform = 2 * petalRadius + 5;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    let container = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${i * transform}, ${j * transform})`);
    drawSunflower(container, i * 5 + j + 1);
  }
}
```

```css
g > path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```